# How to add the js files to specfic modules only

Tags: 6, javascript

I am having a module and am adding the js files which is using on the top of the module file as follows :

```
drupal_add_js(drupal_get_path("module", "notification") . "/js/jquery.js");
```

But the problem is this js file appear in the whole site and makes things messy . I need this file should appear in the notification module only. Another problem is the by default `D6 using the jquery.js (which is an older version 1.2.1)` and  by default its taking from the `sites/misc` path .its taking the old $.browser function and all !! .  And when am including the latest version it makes conflict with the oldest version  . How to solve this ?

Comment: What is the module for? If it's just for admin pages you can include the js in the admin theme. You also can include JS only on certain pages and turn off the default Drupal js files - preprocess functions are one method of doing that.

Answer (score 1):

It is, of course, not possible. The problem is:

- JS files, by the nature of WWW, are added to HTML output
- *All* modules participate in creation of *one* HTML output
- You want to add JS "only to module", but because there is no isolation between parts of HTML output, it's plainly not doable.

---

To address what you didn't really ask, but probably need to know:

Never just add jQuery on your own. That's pretty dangerous thing to do and pretty much always *will* mess things up. There is [jQuery Update](https://www.drupal.org/project/jquery_update) module to address this need. It's not perfect, but way better than anything you will be able to create yourself now - because it was tested by hundreds of thousands.

Comment: $.browser making big problem . its used in lots of places in d6

Comment: And it says Drupal 6 to jQuery 1.3.2 in that module . but i need to use **on** functions , how ?

Comment: @Icecreamsandwich don't. Simple as that. It didn't exist in any jQuery version compatible with Drupal 6 so you can't use it unless you are willing to re-script everything else or upgrade to Drupal 7.